# Creating Functions in JQuery to Avoid Writing the Same Code Again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using a Twitch API that receives information about a specific channel then prepends it to the HTML document. The code that prepends the information is used over and over. I was wondering how exactly do you create a function that could avoid repetition and be called throughout the document?

The codepen can be found here: http://codepen.io/sibraza/pen/AXRRvq

Here is the JQuery Code thats gets used repeatedly:

```
$("#follower-Info").prepend("<div class ='row'>" + "<div class = 'col-md-4'>" + "<img src='" + logo + "'>" + "</div>" + "<div class='col-md-4'>" + name +"</div>"+ "<div class ='col-md-4'>" + status + "</div></div>")
```

Would something like this work:

```
function addThis(){

        $("#follower-Info").prepend("<div class ='row'>" + "<div class = 'col-md-4'>" + "<img src='" + logo + "'>" + "</div>" + "<div class='col-md-4'>" + name +"</div>"+ "<div class ='col-md-4'>" + status + "</div></div>")

   }
```

And then I can could call addThis() after each $.getJSON request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work, but you need to pass `name`, `logo` and `status` as parameters to the function. You can also remove the redundant string concatenation:

```
function addThis(name, logo, status) {
    $("#follower-Info").prepend('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><img src="' + logo + '"></div><div class="col-md-4">' + name + '</div><div class="col-md-4">' + status + '</div></div>');
}
```

Then you can call it from within your `$.getJSON` handler:

```
addThis('Foo', 'bar.jpg', 'online');
```

Comment: How come using addThis(logo, status, name) under each handler doesn't work correctly? Those three parameters are declared locally under each handler.

Comment: Without seeing your code I would guess they are not in scope of the function.

Comment: The code can be seen if you visit the link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/sibraza/pen/AXRRvq

Comment: You define the `addThis()` function in that code, but you never call it.

Comment: Okay, I was able to figure out what I did wrong. The order of the parameters was incorrect.